# Automatically map Azure drive on Win2012 R2 server

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

When I use the following command to mount an Azure File share on a Win2012 R2 server using Windows PowerShell ISE v4.0,

```
$acctKey = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "storageaccountkey>" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "Azure\storageaccountname", $acctKey
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net\company" -Credential     $credential
```

it maps the drive as: company (\storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net)(Z:)

But when I add the .ps1 file to the local group policy editor (gpedit.msc) on our Win2012 R2 server,

Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)->Startup->Powershell scripts

in order for the drive to get mapped each time the server restarts, it maps the drive like this: Disconnected Network Drive (Z:)

I want the drive to be mapped automatically when the server restarts as: company (\storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net)(Z:)

How do I acomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to do it once, dont have to do it each time:

```
net use <desired-drive-letter>: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name> <storage-account-key> /user:Azure\<storage-account-name>
cmdkey /add:<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net /user:AZURE\<storage-account-name> /pass:<storage-account-key>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows